# How to Generate generate_env_file.py environment file for GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables

How can I generate `generate_env_file.py` in GCP?

I have a similar one in AWS.

```py
import os
import boto3

ssm = boto3.client('ssm')

ci_ref = os.environ["CI_REF"]

ssm_param_paths = {
    "apiUrl": "/infra-dev/{}/api_url".format(ci_ref)
}

ssm_param_values = {}

for key, path in ssm_param_paths.items():
    print(key, path)
    parameter = ssm.get_parameter(Name=path, WithDecryption=True)
    ssm_param_values[key] = parameter['Parameter']['Value']

ssm_param_values['apiVersion'] = "/latest" if ci_ref.startswith("dev-") else "/stable"

ssm_param_values['collabVersion'] = "https://XXXX.cloud" if ci_ref == "prod" else "https://XXX.{}.XXX.cloud".format(ci_ref)

for env_key, env_value in ssm_param_values.items():
    os.system( 'find . -type f -name .env.terraform -exec sed -i "s+<<<%s>>>+%s+g" {} \;'% (env_key, env_value) )

if ci_ref.startswith("dev-"):
    with open(".env.terraform", "a") as f:
        f.write("\nREACT_APP_LATEST_API_VERSION = '/latest'\nREACT_APP_STABLE_API_VERSION = '/stable'\n")
```

Comment: Please clean up, correctly format, and indent the Python code.

Comment: Learn how to show your complete code properly. You need to indent it all by the standard amount. At the moment, the python indented code is the only code rendering properly.

Comment: indentation is done